# Securing Rest APIs

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-security-rest, jooby

I have two set of RestAPIs used for same application developed on two different frameworks.

One on SpringBoot secured using OAuth 2. Second set of APIs developed on Jooby microframework of RestAPIs.

Since the services on Jooby are not secure how can i do that? So that both set of APIs are secured.

The Login is working in conjunction with SpringBoot App and OAuth 2.0 and same user credentials should be used for jooby apis as well. Does it make sense to put some sort of gateway common for both the set of apis?

Answer (score 0):

Well, security is a broad topic and frameworks implement security guidelines and support when becoming mature. Even I don't have any prior experiences with Jooby, after referring their [documents](https://jooby.org/doc/security/) I found a couple of support libraries and extensions.
Moreover, you can follow [this](https://github.com/shieldfy/API-Security-Checklist) great Github repo as a checklist and implement what relevant to your context.

If you can provide more implementation details about your login, I can give a more specific answer. But it seems common gateway isn't really necessary and you can use authentication credentials such as tokens directly with your Jooby API's as well. See [pac4j](https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j) which is listed under Jooby documents.